# Name and Date Count in Excel

Tags: excel, count

I have been searching multiple sites trying to find an answer to this question, and if it is possible for excel to perform something like this, but here is my situation.

I have a logbook. After every call, our firefighters open the excel file and input call information about the call to log it. The information includes the following:

[Call Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkMwh.png)

This continues throughout the whole year. Separated cells for each Position, Unit, Name, Nature, Etc. all within one "call info box". What I am looking to do is count how many times a name appears on the calls throughout each month. So basically how many calls say "T. Name" responded to between 1/1/21 and 1/31/21. We receive multiple calls a day so there are multiple call info boxes that have the same date. The dates do not line up with the names.

I figured out how to see how many times a date between or equal to 1/1/21 and 1/31/21 appears so I am able to reference individual month call totals all off of our "Call Log" sheet, but the names is where the complication for me is coming in. As a workaround I currently copy all of January's calls into a separate sheet labeled "January" and have it count the person's name, but I am hoping to cut out that extra step and find a way for it to count everything using only the "Main Log" sheet.

Is it possible for Excel to perform such a function to take the total number of input dates between or equal to 1/1/21 and 1/31/21 and see how many times a name appears on those calls, without having to copy and paste the calls for the month into a separate sheet for each individual month?

Also, I am looking to have it set up where it does NOT count the name if the nature of the call is "EMS". EMS calls do not count toward our firefighters' call percentage.

Purpose of this is to generate a call percentage for each individual. Percentage of calls they responded to in the month, as well as percentage of calls they've responded to for the entire year. Is such a thing possible with the way this logbook is laid out? Thanks.

---

Data after formula input for pivot table:

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7WbP.jpg)
[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eds2C.jpg)

Comment: I would look at using countifs() based on the list of (unique) names then specifying the date range.

Comment: Can you post an image of the data? It's hard to tell which data is in which cell. As long as there is a structure, you can rearrange and analyze. Do you need a formula based solution or VBA is fine too?

Comment: I edited my post to include an image as well as asked an additional question.
I tried setting up a countif using the date range as well as the name, but it appeared that the formula was reading the sheet as "If there is a date range between X and Y then count the number of names on the sheet" so it would still count all names, whether they responded in January or other months. I'm unsure if I was just inputting the formula wrong.
@EvilBlueMonkey I have not messed with VBA but if a VBA solution is provided I could look up some tutorials on how to work VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the human-friendly arrangement of the module. I'd say the "easiest" way is to rearrange the data in order to make it computer-friendly so a pivot table can read it. In a sheet of your choice, put in the specified cell the given formula/value:

**Cell A1:**

```
Sheet
```

as header of the sheet list.

**Cell A2:**

```
January
```

as the name of the sheet with the call logs of January

**Cell A3:**

```
February
```

as the name of the sheet with the call logs of February

**Cell A4-A13:**

you got it, type the rest of the call logs sheet name.

**Cell D1:**

```
 Month
```

as header of the month list.

**Cell D2:**

```
 =IF(D1="Month",INDEX(A:A,2),IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(D1&"!B:B"),"Call Number")*12>TRUNC((CELL("row",D2)-CELL("row",INDIRECT("E"&MAX(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D$1:D1)*1/(D$1:D1=D1),1)-1,1))))/5-0.1,0)*12+1,D1,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(D1,A:A,0)+1)))
```

**Cell E1:**

```
 Row
```

as header of the row list.

**Cell E2:**

```
 =TRUNC(COUNTIF($D$1:D2,D2)/5-0.1)*12+1
```

**Cell F1:**

```
 Call Number
```

as header of the call number list.

**Cell F2:**

```
 =INDEX(INDIRECT(D2&"!"&"C2",FALSE),$E2+1)
```

**Cell G1:**

```
 Date
```

as header of the date list.

**Cell G2:**

```
 =INDEX(INDIRECT(D2&"!"&"C2",FALSE),$E2+5)
```

**Cell H1:**

```
 Nature
```

as header of the nature list.

**Cell H2:**

```
 =INDEX(INDIRECT(D2&"!"&"C5",FALSE),$E2)
```

**Cell I1:**

```
 Off
```

as header of the officers list.

**Cell I2:**

```
 =IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(D2&"!"&"C"&((CELL("row",I1)-CELL("row",I$1))/5-TRUNC((CELL("row",I1)-CELL("row",I$1))/5,0))*10+5,FALSE),$E2+2)="","",INDEX(INDIRECT(D2&"!"&"C"&((CELL("row",I1)-CELL("row",I$1))/5-TRUNC((CELL("row",I1)-CELL("row",I$1))/5,0))*10+5,FALSE),$E2+2))
```

Then select the range D2:I2 and drag it down to report its formulas until they returns errors. You should now have a computer-friendly list. You can use it as a source for a pivot table. I'd suggest to put: Nature in the filters; Off in columns; Month and Date in rows; counts of Call Number in values. Of course once you've pasted the formulas, you can move them from their positions. So if you want to put them in the Main sheet, just create the columns you need to place them in the correct addresses and then move them as you please.

---

---

---

### Extra tip

I assume that you tend to manually report your data in the log; to accomplish that, you copy-paste-clear-compile an old log. Using VBA you could make this process faster, safer and you could also store the data in an already computer-friendly way while keeping the log format for the human interation. This way you wouldn't need all these formulas to rearrange the data.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and see how it goes. Sorry for the long response back. I didn't get back into work until today to be able to fully read the comment and prep it to add into the excel. And I am slightly confused on what you mean by manually reporting data. My apologies. 7 am came too quick and not fully awake yet haha.

Comment: I input the formulas and for D2, it says too many arguments for the formula. When I hit OK it highlights the last 0 in "-1,1))))/5-0,1,0)" and reads the argument as a trunc. Is there only supposed to be two values after the / or is there an error somewhere else?

Comment: Aw, yeah. It must be the ",". My Excel is not in english and i have to translate my formulas. So far i had never translated a decimal value so i didn't considered that. Probably changing it to `-1,1))))/5-0.1,0)` will fix it. The same goes for the E2 formula. By "manually reporting" i mean someone typing in the data in your sheet.

Comment: Ohh ok. Yeah it is all manually input, BUT, I went based off your format and I created a "table" With Columns of: Call Number      Date     Nature       Officer   Engineer   Firefighter  Firefighter 2   Firefighter 3   Firefighter 4   Radio Op   Radio Asst   Standby    Standby 2.

I set up the formulas to check if Nature = EMS. If it does, it doesn't return any values and leaves cell blank. If not, it checks the specific cell dependent on the info requested (Off, Eng, etc). This allows me to check the main log sheet for how many times a name appears, and doesn't count EMS.

Comment: They are all set up as tables. Is there a way to have excel check each table for a date and if the date is within the range, say January, count the value? Without having to manually input each table to check, because that is A LOT of tables haha. If so I will then be able to reference the main sheet for all I'm looking to do. The tables are already present all the way down our entire logbook so when they input another call it is automatically updated on the computer-friendly table.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you came up to. Why are you having multiple tables? The solution i granted allowed you to make a single table on a single sheet harvesting data automatically from each monthly sheet. You can create a pivot table from such sheet and have a report. You can even [create a column to be used as a dynamic filter](https://superuser.com/questions/1271447/is-it-possible-to-set-an-excel-pivot-table-filter-value-to-a-cell-reference) for the dates or just filter the pivot table to cut off the EMS.

Comment: Sorry. My apologies. I had done it after creating the solution you provided as a quick workaround in case I got pulled from the sheet. We ended up being really busy today. I am far from an expert at Excel and appreciate all the help you've given. I updated my original post with images of the answer you provided and how it looks in the pivot table.  I am very green when it comes to this specific thing, so I am struggling to figure out what needs to be adjusted so the data is displayed properly. Not sure if I input something wrong or not. The table only shows two names and two natures.

Comment: I fixed the #Name? issue in the Call Number and Date columns (falso didn't translate to false) but it only returns two call numbers. The first call for January, and the first call for February.

Comment: The problem should be in the formula of cell D2. To be sure of it you might try to manually type in the sheets' name. Purpuse of that formula is to check how many calls are in each given sheet and display their name in order for the formulas in column E to return the correct rows. I can't think of a reason why it shouldn't be working.